# Checks not cashed

Tags: check

I sent numerous checks to a company, they were bill pay checks from my local credit union, the first few we're cashed but the last 8 $100.00 checks were refunded to me after 90 days of not being cashed. Now they want their money.

I didn't realize the money had been refunded because it came back $100 at a time like it went out.  I received an invoice and not all the payments were showing​ so I asked the to please look into it, my account did not reflect the payments. Initially she replied that she would look into it and get back to me. That was last July 2016. January of 2017 she sent me a statement saying I owed her $1240 from an original $1300 balance, but later she states she cashed $550 of my checks, so now I owe $750.

Am I still responsible to pay?

Comment: How did she cash $750 when you only sent $100 checks?

Answer (score 11):

You're certainly still responsible to pay what you owe the company given that: 1. for whatever reason, the recipient never received the checks. and 2. the money was credited back to you, albeit in a less than timely manner.

However, if you take the time to explain the situation to the business, and show them proof that you sent the payments I would guess they would probably be willing to work with you on removing any late fees you have been assessed or possibly setting up a payment plan.

Also, if you have been charged any overdraft or minimum balance fees by your bank while they held your money for the payments that was eventually credited back to your account, you might be able to get them to refund those if you explain what has happened.

This is really a perfect example though of why balancing your checking account is as important today as it ever was.